# jQuery Draggable: grab position from a wrap/unwrapped div & set that position on another div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, draggable

I want to drag a div to another position, set it there permanently (until I drag it again), so even when I unwrap the draggable element, it still stays in that position. As of now, as soon as I unwrap it, it bounces back to where it was originally.

Check out my fiddle here

```
   See Below:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u8hab68y/3/

Also, note, that I want to be able to do this as many times as possible. So, once it is in the new location, i should be able to wrap it at that location again, drag it, set it at another new location, and do the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/u8hab68y/6/
(updated it so there is no offset anymore)

I basically added a inPosition class which is toggeled when the element gets unwrapped and adds

```
position: absolute;
```

to the element.

Also I stored the x and y value of the dragable wrapper in the #thing element and set is as css values, as soon as the element gets unwrapped (with a offset right now, as the wrapper has a 10px border).

For the re-wrapping, you need to add some functionality, to change the wrapper elements position to the position of the #thing element, but this works similar as the other way round.

Comment: But, if I unwrap and re-wrap, it should be at the new location. On your code, I can move it, unwrap it and, boom, its at the new position. But, if I click wrap again, it goes back to the original spot. If I decide to wrap it again, it should start at its previous spot, if that makes sense.

Comment: an other option would be to just set the wrapper to draggable( "disable" ), so it just not dragable as long you are not activating it again